# Codeigniter Loading external site in default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not able to figure this out on my own so here I am asking for your help.

How do I load a website that I already made as a view in the code igniter default controller?

I put my website under a folder name site, and in the default controller I loaded the view site/index , but then in my site there are problems with the includes and redirects... I don't know why, I guess the way the site usually works with redirecting isn't compatible with code igniter style

edit: I guess I would have to turn off CI engine for this site, but I don't know why, because I would still need codeingiter to manage other parts of my application

Answer (score 1):

"CodeIgniter can be told to load a default controller when a URI is not present, as will be the case when only your site root URL is requested. To specify a default controller, open your application/config/routes.php file and set this variable:
$route['default_controller'] = 'Blog';

Where Blog is the name of the controller class you want used. If you now load your main index.php file without specifying any URI segments you'll see your Hello World message by default."

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

fragment copied from that link , you should put the controllers classname in that config, not the view

Comment: But I Don't want any controller, it's like I have a sub-site already made without using any framework, and I'm trying to load that sub site in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's better to choose one of these options:

1. Modify the existing site to a CodeIgniter site.
2. Keep your site separate from the CodeIgniter site, and just link between the two sites.

The way you are trying to do it seems very useless and causing a lot of extra trouble.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a good approach. I think I'm going to link between the two sites, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the redirect function in your controller.  If you supply a full URL you can go to any other page.  You will, of course, leave your CI app.

```
redirect('http://www.example.net/page_in_external_site/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the APPPATH constant when defining the paths for the includes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but you can try using a view template with an iframe, and you can pass the URL to the src property of the iframe. That way you can display your site inside a view, but still can't get access to the vars passed to the view from your site.

Answer (score 0):

In system/Core/Loader.php change the line 141 to look like this:

$this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'views/' => TRUE, FCPATH => TRUE);

and to get the view is simple:

$this->load->view('application/ PATH_TO_VIEW');